# Firefox Extension How to Detect Session

Tags: firefox-addon

I am trying to figure out how can we detect if we are logged in to a site from Firefox Extensions.
I am planning to invoke a rest api in the target site to detect if the user is loggedin or not. I am not sure what is the right place to make such calls.

Going though documentation, seems like main.js is could be the place where I want to put such method, but then I am not sure how to call form my views this particular method in main.js

Comment: What about check if a cookie exists would that work? Or cookies contents?

Answer (score 0):

There is no *generic* way to  determine that a user is logged in to a site. Every site can, and does, choose their own method of doing so.  The most common method is to store a session cookie on the user's machine through the browser.  However, the specifics are nearly certain to be different at each site.  There is also the question of, in your situation, if there is the possibility that the site permits the user to be logged in for an extended period of time (i.e. not just in a session).

The most probable way to successfully determine how the fact that the user is logged in is recorded on the machine is to look at the differences between what cookies are stored (for the site) prior to the user being logged in, while the user is logged in, and after the user is logged out.  There are a [large number of extensions dealing with cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=cookies&platform=WINNT&appver=34.0a2).  One of them should probably be able to help with letting you look at the information you need to examine for this investigation.

Once you have that information, you can use a variety of different interfaces in Firefox to access the cookies and see if the user is logged in. Obviously, you will want to [listen for changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#Cookies), and/or listen for a page from the site to be loaded ([overlay/bootstrapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listen_for_Page_Load), [SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listen_for_Page_Load)) rather than pooling for changes in the cookies.

MDN refs about the cookie interfaces:

- Deal with individual cookies:[nsICookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookie), [nsICookie2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookie2) [nsICookieManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieManager), [nsICookieManager2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieManager2#add%28%29)
- Deals with the entire cookie string: [nsICookieService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieService)